# Php dom - remove child - leaves </> tag

Tags: php, xml, dom

After using removechild, < / > tag is left.

In my code, you can see I wanted to remove workspace that contains 'bar' application.

After successful remove, < WORKSPACE/ > is still there. I want to get rid of it. How it can be done?

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/07f17c110fdee579a2eabca138004958e5d17829

Comment: Please put the code fragment in your question in addition to posting it in sandbox service, so in future if someone is looking for similar issue, he will be able fully understand your question, even if the code fragment is removed from sandbox service.

Comment: It will be removed? Okay understand

Comment: It depends on the service. JSbin removes snippets after 3 months, I do not know about the sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com, but any external service can do anything with their data. What is on stackoverflow, stays here as long as the stackoverflow istelf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are retrieving the parent of `APPLICATION` which is `WORKSPACE` with

```
$parent = $app->parentNode;
```

So if you want to remove the workspace itself, you just need to retrieve the parent of `WORKSPACE` and apply the same method (`removeChild` with the `$parent` as node to remove)

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I added $superParent that is parent of old parent, then, $superParent->removeChild($parent) worked like charm http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ef2a00c37023e9afdd4996fb9287f7810bdb5fed